# Asian handicap bets combination

Tags: football, strategy, betting

What happens if I bet on 5 games over 1.0/1.5 goals and 3 of them ended over 1.5, but the rest two only with one goal?

How is the outcome calculated?

Answer (score 4):

[This is the wikipedia page that explain asian handicap betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_handicap).

In a case of multiple bet you have to calculate in this way:

- bet Y
- event 1 over 1.5 => win (coefficient X1)
- event 2 over 1.5 => win (coefficient X2)
- event 3 over 1.5 => win (coefficient X3)
- event 4 over 1 => draw (win divided by 2)
- event 5 over 1 => draw (win divided by 2)

So in this case your outcome is:
 **- Y*((X1*X2*X3)/4)**

For each event you can think in this way:

- half betting on over 1.0 (you win 5 out of 5 bets)
- and half on over 1.5 (you win 3 out of 5 times)

Comment: the option is 1.0/1.5 You have a push if you play single, but i am not sure what happens in combination

Comment: as i said that is an asian betting

Comment: @KirilMladenov I update the reply because I was thinking about a normal betting on asian matches